# Going full-screen and exiting that mode, makes status bar disappear

Tags: android, statusbar

I am going from one context executing this to go into full screen mode..

```
activity.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

Then when I leave the full-screen mode I call this...

```
getActivity().window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
```

Problem is.. the status bar up top is gone.  What do I do?

*edit* It looks like the status bar does appear, but it's ending up behind the main content.

Answer (score 0):

Hack solution rather than playing with individual flags outright...

I just grabbed the int value of decorView.systemUiVisibility and set it to that when I dismiss my full screen mode.  This resolved it...